# mkvirtualenv OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: ubuntu, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

Currently i had a website running with root user on ubuntu(linux), and hence i want to shift it to normal user with root privileges.

So created a new user with root privileges and copied all the required stuff(code, folders) from root user to normal users including virtualenvs folder

Now when i tried to create a new virtual env on new user i was getting below error

```
mkvirtualenv hello
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 824, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 984, in create_environment
    site_packages=site_packages, clear=clear, symlink=symlink))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1158, in install_python
    mkdir(lib_dir)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 447, in mkdir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 150, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 150, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'hello'
```

how can we rectify this ?

Comment: Have you `chown`ed the copied folders?